# converting string to date and truncating

Tags: date, google-bigquery, truncation

In BigQuery, I have a field called initiated_date that takes string values like

19-FEB-13 08.44.22.000000 PM -05:00
19-JUN-13 07.58.32.423526 PM -04:00

I would like to return only the dates like '2013-02-19', '2013-06-19'. How do I do that?

I have tried DATE(initiated_date) but it is giving me null values.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions  You need to use one of these.... as you can see it doesn't accept the format you have unfortunately.

Comment: It DOES depend on what way you're calling your query, but pretty much your only chance of getting the format you want would be to convert it through code, AFTER having retrieved it

Comment: (SUBSTR((STRING (CLAIM_INITIATED_TIME)), 1,9)) gives me 19-FEB-13, which is a string. But what to do after that? I could not convert it to the format that I wanted.

Comment: read the reference I sent you. It's not looking for 19-FEB-13 but a timestamp. If you don't have a timestamp, the Date() function will not take it. Once you have 19-FEB-13 in your code, I'm sure you can convert it, no? through the query itself, it's doable, but cumbersome and definitely not pretty

Answer (score 4):

If you really want pure SQL solution to do such transformation - here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT yyyy + '-' + IF(LENGTH(m) < 2, '0' + m, m) + '-' + dd FROM (
SELECT 
  '20' + SUBSTR(x, 8, 2) as yyyy,
  STRING(CAST((INSTR('JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC',
                      SUBSTR(x, 4, 3)) - 1) / 3 + 1 AS INTEGER)) as m,
  SUBSTR(x, 1, 2) as dd
FROM
(SELECT '19-FEB-13 08.44.22.000000 PM -05:00' AS x),
(SELECT '02-DEC-12 18.24.12.000000 PM -05:00' AS x),
(SELECT '19-JUN-13 07.58.32.423526 PM -04:00' AS x))
```

It produces the following output:

```
2013-02-19   
2012-12-02   
2013-06-19
```

Comment: as I said.. cumbersome and definitely not pretty. But I appreciate the cleverness of the INSTR :P